# Bokeh + Python - hover over vbar, while data coming from pandas

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have a pandas dataframe I am pulling data from and showing as a bar plot using Bokeh. What I want is show the max value of each bar upon hover. This is the first day I'm using Bokeh and I already changed the code a couple times and I'm really confused how to set it up. I added the:

```
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("x_ax", "@x_ax"), ("y_ax", "@y_ax")]))
```

line, but just don't understand it.

Here's the code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, ranges, LabelSet
from bokeh.plotting import figure, save, gridplot, output_file

# prepare some data
# x = pd.Series(range(1,36))
x_ax = FAdf['SampleID']
y_ax = FAdf['First Run Au (ppm)']

# output to static HTML file
output_file("bars.html")

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(x_range=x_ax, title="Batch results", x_axis_label='sample', y_axis_label='Au (ppm)',
           toolbar_location="above", plot_width=1200, plot_height=800)

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("x_ax", "@x_ax"), ("y_ax", "@y_ax")]))

# setup for the bars
p.vbar(x=x_ax, top=y_ax, width=0.9)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0

# turn bar tick labels 45 deg
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = np.pi/3.5

# show the results
show(p)
```

Sample from the FAdf database:

```
SampleID:
0                 KR-19  349
1                 KR-19  351
2                    Blank_2
3                 KR-19  353

First Run Au (ppm):
0      0.019
1      0.002
2      0.000
3      0.117
```

Comment: Could you add a small sample of the `FAdf` data so that this code can be run?

Comment: Just added to the main post. Thanks!

Comment: You can use something like `p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("Sample:", "@x"), ("Au (ppm):", "@top")]))`. This will display something like "Sample: KR-19". `@x` refers to the `x` parameter of `vbar` and `@top` to the `top` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC  That worked. If anyone has a similar issue it may also be worth adding: "{1.111}"  right after after (at)top to preserve the original (3 in this case) decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass actual literal data sequences to a glyph method like you have above, then Bokeh uses generic field names like "x" and "y" since it has no way of knowing any other names use. These are the columns you would need to configure the hover tool with:

```
tooltips=[("x_ax", "@x"), ("y_ax", "@y")])
```

Alternatively, you can pass a `source` argument to the `vbar` method so that the columns have the column names that you prefer. This is described in the Users Guide:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html